# Apache: Redirect results in too many redirect, but not with Rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite, 301-redirect

Firstly: is not a duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever).

I'd want to know why in my case Rewrite works but Redirect does not.

I have the following in httpd.conf:

```
#Redirect 301 / https://mx1.example.com/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1" [R,L]
```

That works fine, http:// goes to https://

If I uncomment the Redirect line and comment the las 3 lines, curl results in:

```
* Maximum (50) redirects followed
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

This is the output os  `httpd -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  mx1.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: _RH_HAS_HTTPPROTOCOLOPTIONS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

Why does Redirect does not work?

Output of `httpd -DDUMP_CONFIG`:

```
Listen 80
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName mx1.example.com
<Directory />
  AllowOverride none
  Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.html
<Files ".ht*">
  Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
  AllowOverride None
  Options None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
EnableSendfile on
#Redirect 301 / https://mx1.example.com/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1" [R,L]
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/httpd/icons/"
<Directory "/usr/share/httpd/icons">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif /core
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif */core.*
AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
Alias /sareport /usr/local/sendmailanalyzer/www
<Directory /usr/local/sendmailanalyzer/www>
  Options ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  DirectoryIndex sa_report.cgi
  Require all granted
</Directory>
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName mx1.example.com:443
  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
  TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
  LogLevel warn
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mx1.example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/mx1.example.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mx1.example.com/fullchain.pem
  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]"          nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown          downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log           "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
UserDir disabled
<Directory "/home/*/public_html">
  AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
  Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
  Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
  Options -Indexes
  ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /noindex/css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
httpd (pid 13348) already running
```

Comment: Huh? Where are the rest of your virtual hosts?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's is all I have ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So where did you put the rewrite rules that are shown above?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ok, I've appended the complete configuration of Apache.